# TagsIndexRoute is never called TagsRoute is Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to reproduce example for learning sake part by part from here [Original](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dDWdv/)

and my jsbin is [**MY JSBIN**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/anoFaSef/1/edit)
My Post routes are

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     return this.modelFor('posts');
  }
}); 
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('post');
  } 
});
```

and my tags route are exactly same.

> App.TagsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({   model:function(){
>       return this.modelFor('tags');   } });
>
> App.TagsRoute = Em.Route.extend({   model: function(){
>       return this.store.findAll('tag');   } });

while I can display data if my data template name is data-template-name="tags"
I cannot display data with data-template-name="tags/index"

my router map looks like this

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.route('about');
  this.resource('posts',{path:'/posts'},function(){
    this.route('post',{path:':id'});
  });

  this.resource('tags',{path:'/tags'});
});
```

It just silently fails no error message. If in IndexRoute I change from transitionTo('tags') to transitionTo('posts') things work fine no clue where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a documented bug/feature where if your resource has no function argument passed it won't create the index route

```
 this.resource('tags',{path:'/tags'}, function(){});
```

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3995#issuecomment-31200805

> NOTE: If you define a resource using this.resource and do not supply a function, then the implicit resource.index route is not created

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: I am sorry for asking something that I could have figured out by paying more attention. Thanks anyways.

Comment: No worry, I filed the bug and didn't know about it, it's a valid question.